# How to put a arrow/highlight over a text and how to put a image on the right side.

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, highlighting

I woudl like to put my tikzpicture in the spot marked with an X.
And I want to rely two elements together with an arrow and highlight them. 
Thank you.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
~
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 5,
    axis lines=left]
    \addplot coordinates { (2,2) (3,3) (4,4) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
%%%%
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Et comment ça fonctionne?}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Dilatation:= $\alpha \oplus \beta = \{a+b|a\in \alpha \wedge b\in \beta\}$ 
    \item Érosion:= $\alpha \ominus \beta = \{a-b|a\in \alpha \wedge b\in \beta\}$ 

    \end{enumerate}     
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Addition de Minkowski:

    $\alpha_{1} = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$

    $\alpha_{2} = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$

    $\alpha_{1} \oplus \alpha_{2} = \{(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$ 
    \end{itemize}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use `columns` to align the picture with the equations and the `tikzmark` library for the overlaid arrow. Since you are already loading PGF/TikZ, this does not involve much additional overhead, which might otherwise be considered overkill for a simple arrow by the computationally thrifty.

If you want to highlight a lot, I would look at specialised packages (e.g. `soul`). Otherwise, for just the odd thing, I'd go with the flow and add it to the `tikzmark` overlay using `blend mode=multiply` on the highlighting scope and a suitable opacity. Opacity of `1` struck me as a bit over-the-top, so I went with half that, but your kilometres may obviously vary according to taste.

Note that `fragile` is unnecessary here, as far as I can tell, and that several of your packages and libraries are not needed for the MWE so removed here.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Et comment ça fonctionne?}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Dilatation:= $\alpha \tikzmark{a}\oplus\tikzmark{b} \beta = \{a+b|a\in \alpha \wedge b\in \beta\}$
    \item Érosion:= $\alpha \ominus \beta = \{a-b|a\in \alpha \wedge b\in \beta\}$
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}[T]{.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \tikzmark{e}Addition \tikzmark{c}de\tikzmark{d} Minkowski\tikzmark{f}:

        $\alpha_{1} = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$

        $\alpha_{2} = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$

        $\alpha_{1} \oplus \alpha_{2} = \{(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}[T]{.5\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \begin{axis}[
          xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
          ymin = 0, ymax = 5,
          axis lines=left]
          \addplot coordinates { (2,2) (3,3) (4,4) };
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \foreach \i in {a,b,c,d,e,f} \coordinate (\i) at ({pic cs:\i});
    \foreach \i/\j in {a/b,c/d} \coordinate (\i\j) at ($(\i)!.5!(\j)$);
    \begin{scope}[blend mode=multiply, opacity=.5]
      \path [fill=cyan] ([yshift=.65ex]ab) circle (1.5ex);
      \path [draw=cyan, line width=3ex, shorten >=-.5ex, shorten <=-.5ex] ([yshift=1ex]e) -- ([yshift=1ex]f);
    \end{scope}
    \draw [thick, -{Stealth[bend]}, shorten >=-2.5pt] ([yshift=-2.5pt]ab) .. controls +(1.25,-.5) and +(.75,.75) .. ([yshift=.75*\baselineskip]cd);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrows & alignment]

Comment: Doesn't work. I am using TexMaker. http://i.imgur.com/TPm6lAk.png

Comment: I just fixed it with "\usetikzlibrary{babel}". I have no idea why this work, but it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Babel makes characters active which TikZ likes to parse. It may depend on versions whether you need to do this explicitly - I'm not sure why I wouldn't need to if you did. Glad you found a solution - `doesn't work` is really not very informative.